# Closed and bounded subset of $l_\infty$ such that it is not totally bounded.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Is there any subset of $l_\infty$ such that:

1. The subset is closed and bounded.
2. The subset is not totally bounded.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What does it mean to be bounded?  Totally bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$l_\infty$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, so the closed unit ball is necessarily not compact. It is, however, both closed and bounded. Since compact subsets of metric spaces are exactly those which are complete and totally bounded and it is complete (closed subsets of a complete metric space are complete), it must *not* be totally bounded.

Comment: Note that $\|e_n - e_m\| = 2$ for all $n \neq m \in \Bbb N$ (the standard unit vectors, that lie in the closed unit ball) which immediately implies that this ball is not totally bounded. Take $\varepsilon=1$ and we need infinitely balls of that radius to even cover the unit vectors.